# Using RTKGPS+ with smart phone?

Tags: rtkgps+

I am beginner and new for app RTKGPS+ in smartphone. I am interest to use this program to use my smart phone as the rover by use GPS signal from itself. And take the data from base station to this program for my survey onsite with accurate required less than 1m.

Can I do this with this program and how I can do that?

Can I also get information about manual for this program?

Comment: Basic docs for RTKGPS+: https://github.com/eltorio/RtkGps. Since it's Android port of RTKLIB, manual for RTKLIB: http://www.rtklib.com/prog/manual_2.4.2.pdf

Answer (score 2):

I would like to do accuracy better than 30 feet with a smartphone too, either Android or iPhone.  RTKLIB's RTKGPS+ looked promising, BUT, in the Google Play store (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=gpsplus.rtkgps&hl=en_US)
it says:

> This application can compute precise GPS positions using RTKLIB
>   algorithms (RTK or PPP) but for this you need a supported -external-
>   GPS with raw carrier phase output.

This is not a "standard" GPS like those embedded into your phone or your car, the cheapest one you can find is something like uBlox LEA-6T .

THERE IS NO WAY to use the GPS found in Samsung Galaxy(s) nor any phone I seen.
But there is a special test mode witch use the internal GPS for testing only, obviously none of the precision algorithm found in RTKLIB can be use.